# Difference between globalScope , corountineScope and viewScope in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What is the difference between globalScope , coroutineScope and viewModelScope and when to use them inside Kotlin programming with viewModelScope still under development?

I have gone through below link 
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-iii-real-work-2ba8a2ec2f45

I know corountineScope will be having scope until {} for which it was called.
Also we have supervisorScope which is similar to coroutineScope ,
viewModelScope having scope till ViewModel .
Global scope - does it have till application works or activity ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`GlobalScope` is a singleton scope that returns a completely empty `coroutineContext`. Since there's no `Job` associated with it, you cannot cancel it, so its lifecycle is basically "forever".

A separate instance of `viewModelScope` is attached to every instance of `ViewModel`. It runs out when the `ViewModel` is destroyed.

`coroutineScope` and `supervisorScope` are suspendable functions that establish their own local scope, run the block you pass to them within that scope, and return when all the work inside is done, including all the coroutines launched within their scope.

Comment: what do you mean there's no job associated with it? Because I can do `val job = GlobalScope.launch()` and then `job.cancel()`

Comment: Try `GlobalScope.coroutineContext[Job]` -- or any other key, doesn't matter which (since the context is empty).